# Does DirectoryInfo.GetFiles() return files that are currently being written to/open?

Tags: c#

I am recursively searching through directories, and I just need to make sure that if a file is open, or currently being written to, that it won't be returned in the file list.

(This is for an FTP component, I do not wish to send a file if it is open for writing already)

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Once you get your list back the status of those files could easily change.  Your design, there is something wrong with it.

Comment: In this case, the file will not change.  It is an EDI file being written.  They will never be modified, only created then left alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will return files which are still in use. They're still in the directory, even if you can't currently open them.

Test code to prove it:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        File.Delete("test.tmp");
        // Prints false - the delete worked
        Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetFiles(".")
                                   .Any(x => x.EndsWith("\\test.tmp")));
        using (Stream stream = File.Create("test.tmp"))
        {
            // Prints true, even though the stream is still open
            Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetFiles(".")
                                       .Any(x => x.EndsWith("\\test.tmp")));
        }       
    }
}
```

As Will said, even if you *could* do this, there's no guarantee that you would still be able to open the file a second later. File system checks will only ever be snapshots unless you do something to ensure the consistency yourself - such as opening the file and holding it open.

Comment: The traditional workaround is to download the file into one directory and move it into another once it's fully arrived.  Similar schemes involve a rename instead of a move, but that's essentially the same thing at the file level.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The only way I know to see if a file is locked to try and read it.

Answer (score 0):

You could base a rule on the LastAccessTime of each file?

Comment: Clever, but probably not safe.  The file could be held open without having been recently accessed.

Answer (score 0):

You should first get the list, which will return all the files present in the directory (open or not) and then, before sending the files, open each file catching failure.

If the opening doesn't fail, you can safely send them (nobody will write to or open it). If it fails, you know you cannot open the file and skip it.

Even it it was possible to check on the GetFiles() call, you cannot know that the status is still the same as when you checked the first time.